# CommandText issue when passing data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, csv

I am trying to use VB.NET to read a CSV file and then pass the data to an SQL server table.

I have the below code, but it is failing with:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

"Additional information: ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized"

It seems to fail on this line of code:

```
Dim iRowsInserted As Int32 = _
```

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Full code below:

```
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    table.Columns.Add("ZipCode")
    table.Columns.Add("State")
    table.Columns.Add("City")

    Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\uploads\zipcode.csv")

    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","} ' fields are separated by comma
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True ' each of the values is enclosed with double quotes
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True
    parser.ReadLine()

    Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
        table.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())
    Loop

    Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO tblZipCode (ZipCode,State,City) VALUES (@ZipCode,@State,@City)"
    Dim SqlconnectionString As String = "server=barry-laptop\SQLEXPRESS; database=Test; integrated security=yes"
    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlconnectionString)

        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(Sql, connection) ' create command objects and add parameters
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "ZipCode")
            .Add("@State", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "State")
            .Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "City")
        End With

        Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.InsertCommand = cmd

        '--Update the original SQL table from the datatable
        Dim iRowsInserted As Int32 = _
            adapter.Update(table)

    End Using

End Sub
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Your code won't compile at all. You haven't declared `Sql`. Perhaps it must be `strSql`.

Comment: Thank you, so much - That was the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSql , connection)

is correct